# Function building html string needing to include results from another function

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that is building an HTML string (outStr), as follows:

```
    function ShowUserInfo()
    {
        var userId = $("#users").val();
        if (userId == -1)
        {
            $("#userInfo").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $.getJSON('Services/foobar.svc/GetUserById?userId=' + userId,
                function (data) {
                    var outStr = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
                        //var d = new Date(elem.DateOfBirth);
                        outStr += "<div class=\"user\">" +
                                "   <h3>" + elem.Forename + " " + elem.Surname + "</h3>" +
                                "   <p>Date of birth: " + elem.DateOfBirth + "</p>"
                    });
                    outStr += "<h4>Associated items</h4>"
                    outStr += [*** To do: add results from function ShowUserItemInfo ***];
                    outStr += "</div>"
                    $("#userInfo").show().html(outStr);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Note the ***To do *** part: this is where I am having trouble. I have another function (ShowUserItemInfo) that also builds an HTML string in a similar way. What I would like is to simply be able to call that function and append its resulting HTML string to outStr.

But I just can't get it to work.

Comment: We'll need to see the implementation of that method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ShowUserItemInfo` simply returns a string you could just invoke the method like this.

```
outStr += ShowUserItemInfo();
```

I asume that the function looks something like this:

```
function ShowUserItemInfo(){
    return "<div>Hello world</div>"
}
```

Comment: You're right, of course - and that's just what I initially tried. After further investigation, it appears the error lies elsewhere. Specifically, it seems to be related to a WCF service. I've investigated, but it looks like I am going to have to start a separate thread.